# JS - constructingan array - SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make autocomplete on a research of elements from my Database (wich is on SQL Server).

Here is my PHP request :

```
public function getNomProduitsAutocomplete() {

    $q = '  SELECT NomProduit
            FROM Produit
            WHERE NomProduit LIKE \'a%\' OR NomProduit LIKE \'b%\'
            ORDER BY NomProduit';
    $qResults = $this->fetchAll($q);
    $numItems = count($qResults);
    $i = 0;
    //var_dump($numItems);
    $result = '[ ';

    foreach($qResults as $res){

        if(++$i === $numItems) {
            $result .= '"' .$res['NomProduit'] . '"' ;
        }
        else {
            $result .= '"' .$res['NomProduit'] . '", ';
        }
    }
    $result .= ' ]';

    return $result;
}
```

And the auto complete in js here :

```
    $(function () {
        <?php   
            $p = new Produit(); 
            $produits = $p->getNomProduitsAutocomplete(); 
            //var_dump($produits);
        ?>
        var availableTags2 = <?php echo ($produits); ?>;
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags2
        });
    });
```

and finaly the input for the auto complete :

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

All of this works fine, but ONLY when I have, less than 1 000 elements in the array, it seems.

It actually works with 700 elements (" WHERE NomProduit LIKE \'a%\' OR NomProduit LIKE \'b%\' " as you see), and I would like to get ALL the elements (+/- 4 800 elements) if possible, not only 700...
If you have any ideas... :)
Thanks.

Comment: I note that you are not attempting to escape any of your product names. If I was to guess, one of them includes a `"` symbol, causing your syntax error. As Gahendra has stated in his answer, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output the array; it will handle all the escaping of characters itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not using `josn_encode` function in your **getNomProduitsAutocomplete** function?

You are manually creating the javascript array in PHP, instead collect all your `$res['NomProduit']` in an array say `$js_array` and then use `return json_encode($js_array)`

Comment: So it is that simple... :D
Thanks very much, it works very fine now, but I still don't understand why it worked in some case before... Nevermind ;)
I changed my array to :
  `$tab = Array();
  foreach($qResults as $res){
   $tab[] = $res['NomProduit'];   
  }
  return json_encode($tab);`

Comment: @Robin I totally agree with Phylogenesis. Your old code was having escaping problem thus was giving syntax error, and in your new code json_encode  take care of all escaping.